unresponding cp between two remote cifs share, both on the same distant machine
I have 2 cifs remote share in /etc/fstab on xubuntu machine
//192.168.1.2/THOMAS /media/THOMAS cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,_netdev,iocharset=utf8,vers=2.0,nofail,cache=none,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=100,forcegid 0 0

//192.168.1.2/JACQUES /media/JACQUES cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,_netdev,iocharset=utf8,vers=2.0,cache=none,nofail,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=100,forcegid 0 0

the mount cmd give me
//192.168.1.2/JACQUES on /media/JACQUES type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=2.0,cache=none,username=toto,domain=WORKGROUP,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=100,forcegid,addr=192.168.1.2,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,iocharset=utf8,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1,closetimeo=1,_netdev)

//192.168.1.2/THOMAS on /media/THOMAS type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=2.0,cache=none,username=toto,domain=WORKGROUP,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=100,forcegid,addr=192.168.1.2,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,iocharset=utf8,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1,closetimeo=1,_netdev)

on 192.168.1.2 (debian machine) the smb version is
sudo smbstatus --version
Version 4.13.13-Debian

on local machine the smb version is
sudo smbstatus --version
Version 4.18.6-Ubuntu

For example, when i copy a file from JACQUES to a local disk, i have no problem.
But when i try to copy a file from JACQUES to THOMAS, it hangs. nothing in top, nothing in iotop, i see the file is created in the destination folder but it stays to 0 byte. And when i try to cancel the copy, nothing happened.
I tried with ver=3.0, i tried with cache=strict and before some days i haven't the problem.
when i try to mv a file, smbstatus tells me :
sudo smbstatus -L
Locked files:
Pid          User(ID)   DenyMode   Access      R/W        Oplock           SharePath   Name   Time
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
21140        1000       DENY_NONE  0x120089    RDONLY     LEASE(RH)        

21140        1000       DENY_NONE  0x120196    WRONLY     LEASE(RWH)


and nothing with iotop on the client.
reminder : the problem only happen if source and destination are two different share folder on the same machine
and i have no problem doing exactly the same mv on Windows  :-(
could somebody help me ? thank you.
PS: sorry for my poor english ;-)

i found this
Samba connection issues after the new 6.5.0-27-generic kernel update
and i updated the 12  April, so it seems to be the same pb
downgrade the kernel version correct the problem !
https://www.groovypost.com/howto/how-to-downgrade-the-kernel-in-ubuntu/
